# Как pascal записывает значение в элемент массива?

Tags: pascal

Работает ли паскаль так:

Нужно выполнить операцию mass[4]:=54; :

- Найти адрес начала массива
- К этому адресу прибавить 4*(размер одного элемента массива)
- В полученый адрес записать значение 54

Comment: Ну, если по аналогии с Си, то mass - это и есть адрес начала массива, поэтому искать особо ничего не надо. А так все правильно.

Comment: А в pascal индексы в массиве с 0 (как в C) или с 1 (как в FORTRAN) ?

Comment: В паскале начинаются с нуля

Comment: Как напишете, так и начинаются `>_<`

    type
      m1: array[0..15]; // с нуля
      m2: array[1..16]; // с единицы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mass[4]:=54;
```

Таки что это не получается что ли?

```
var mass=array[0..10] of integer;
```